# scale3d causes iOS Safari to crash

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

We've been building a 3D product preview that purely relies on HTML and CSS. That means there is a lot of CSS for 3D translation, 3D scaling and even some transitions going on. We just now realized, that zooming into this preview on iOS Safari causes the browser to crash. Removing all `scale3d` from the CSS fixes the crashing, but we depend on it. Using the non-standard `zoom` works, but it ignores perspective and is not really an option, unfortunately.

Has anyone experience with complex 3d styling and has found a solution this problem?

Comment: Don't you understand that no one will help you with such a question? Provide a minimal reproducible example of your problem. Without it, I voted to close the issue.

Comment: I can‘t show the code here and it‘s too complex to break it down. I don‘t need anyone to fix a specific problem in the code. I was hoping for someone to have experienced something similar to what I described. If you feel the need to do that, go ahead.